# Using \\ for linebreak in table cell resulting in extended priting of \midrule and \toprule

Tags: tables, tabularx

I am using `\thread{}` for printing a column name and using `\\` for a line break inside a thread. This is resulting in the extended printing of `\midrule` and `\toprule` as shown below in the figure.

[image]

The code I am using is given below

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
\begin{tabular}
{p{\dimexpr0.60\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}
 p{\dimexpr0.40\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}}
   \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth,valign=c]{../matlab/SCEP_mcep_compare/graphs/IotServerCpuUtilization}
    &
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l r c}
    \toprule
    \thead{$\lambda$ }  & \thead{Process \\ CPU \% } & \thead{System \\ CPU \%  }  \\
    \midrule
    10   &  13 &  3     \\
    500  &  70 &  30    \\
    1000 &  83 &  38    \\
    2000 &  84 &  39    \\
    3000 &  84 &  39    \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}                           
    \tabularnewline \vspace*{-4mm}
    \caption{Effect of $\lambda$ CPU and Memory}\label{fig:SCEPQoS0MemoryCPU}
    & \vspace*{-4mm}
    \captionof{table}{Values for \cref{fig:SCEPQoS0MemoryCPU}}\label{tab:SCEPQoS0MemoryCPU}
\end{tabular}\vspace*{-13mm}
\end{figure}
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: You are using [`tabularx`](//ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) *without* an `X`-column. Either use `tabular` (and don't specify a width), or use `tabularx` (with a width like `\linewidth`) and an `X`-column.

Comment: `\thead{}` not `\thread{}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`tabularx`](//ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) requires a width component and sets the table to have that width. If you don't have an `X`-column, columns are set left-to-right using their natural width which may lead to incomplete horizontal usage (as in your case), or content spilling over the pre-specified width. Below I show the intended use - width and an `X`-column:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,caption,makecell}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{tabular}{
    p{\dimexpr0.60\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}
    p{\dimexpr0.40\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}
  }
    \includegraphics[width = \linewidth, valign = c]{example-image}
    &
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X r c}
      \toprule
      \thead{$\lambda$} & \thead{Process \\ CPU \%} & \thead{System \\ CPU \%} \\
      \midrule
      10   &  13 &  3  \\
      500  &  70 &  30 \\
      1000 &  83 &  38 \\
      2000 &  84 &  39 \\
      3000 &  84 &  39 \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \tabularnewline
    \captionof{table}{Effect of $\lambda$ CPU and Memory}
    &
    \captionof{table}{Values for something}
  \end{tabular}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```